# Cisco Router on a Stick IP Addressing

Tags: cisco, router, ip-address

I have been running into IP addressing problems with my Packet Tracer network and VLAN assingments.
I have 2 switches connected to a router, 1 switch has 4 VLAN's and the other has 3 VLAN's
I can't figure out my IP addressing in ???????, I am using 255.255.255.0 for all the VLANS but i cant' figure the IP's for the router and switch's and whether I need to use the VLAN 1 or not.
I want to be able to connect switch to switch, or switch to router, or router to switch to admin them with SSH.

```
        g0/2/0.10 192.168.10.1 | VLAN10 192.168.10.0
        g0/2/0.20 192.168.20.1 | VLAN20 192.168.20.0
        g0/2/0.30 192.168.30.1 | VLAN30 192.168.30.0
        g0/2/0.99 192.168.99.1 | VLAN99 192.168.99.0
        g0/2/0    ???????????? | SWITCH 1
Router            ????????????
        g0/3/0    ???????????? | Switch 2
        g0/2/0.40 192.168.40.1 | VLAN40 192.168.40.0
        g0/2/0.50 192.168.50.1 | VLAN50 192.168.50.0
        g0/2/0.99 192.168.99.1 | VLAN99 192.168.99.0
```

Comment: When you're using sub-interfaces, the main interface doesn't need an address, unless you are using a native VLAN (which appears you aren't).  the switch admin interface can be any one of the interfaces.

Comment: "unless you are using a native VLAN (which appears you aren't)" thats what i was wondering do i need the native vlan running. Also how would switch 1 connect to switch 2 which ip would it use.

Comment: No.  the native VLAN is just like any other.except it's not tagged.  You need to decide which vlan you want to use for switch management.  On the switch, you will configure a VLAN interface with an IP address on that vlan.

Comment: One more thing.  I just noticed you have  the same IP subnet (vlan 99) on 2 different switches.  You can't do that unless you're bridging on your router.  Every VLAN has to have a separate ip subnet.

Comment: I guess that would be my VLAN 99 Admin VLAN

Comment: you can't have the same subnet on 2 different router interfaces.  That's known as a discontiguous subnet, which will not work.  They both van be named VL 99, but they have to have different IP ranges.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

If your configuring router on stick then router ingress interface connecting to switch will be with no ip address assigned

`Router (config)# int f0/0`

`Router(config) #no ip address`

`Router(config)# no shutdown`

Then after create subinterface on intf0/0 interface with creating VLANs and respective vlan gateways example below

`Router(config) #int f0/0 .10`

`Router(config)# ip address 192.168.10.0 255.255.255.0`

`Router(config)#encapsulation dot1 Q 10`

`Router(config)#no shutdown`

*Create as many subinterface with int f0/0.X as per your requirement*

Then after connect router interfàce f0/0  with layer2 switch interface assuming f0/1 is switch interfàce

**Connecting router and switch**

`SwitchD (config)# int f0/1`

`SwitchD(config)#switch mode trunk`

`SwitchD(config) switchport trunk allowed vlans all`

`SwitchD(config)#no shutdown`

Then after connect access switch to switchD with trunk links and connect PC's to access switch and configure access-ports and pass vlan as per your requirements

In this topology all the traffic will reach to router if they want to communicate different vlan . Access-list can be configured in router to restrict and control traffic ..

Answer (score 0):

In Cisco land VLAN1 is special. It carries all the SSDP traffic. As others have mentioned you don't have a "native VLAN" configured so the raw interface has no IP assigned (which is not required).

You will want to configure each switch to have a known static IP that is part of a native VLAN. This will allow you to manage the switches in-band (ssh in) If configured.

If user traffic is going through the switches it is ideal to setup an out of band management network to manage the switches. Use an additional port on the switch and connect it to a dedicated management switch. If it's all internal users (no security concerns) setup in band to conserve ports.

Be mindful to use a non overlapping range for your native VLANs. It need to be routable company wide.

Comment: "_In Cisco land VLAN1 is special. It carries all the SSDP traffic._" No, not at all, you can have a trunk with no native VLAN, and all the layer-2 protocols that do not use VLAN tags will still work correctly. In fact, the Cisco recommendations are to not use a native VLAN, and to block VLAN 1 on trunks, all for security. DTP, CDP, PAgP, LACP, etc. do cross a link as untagged, but they are link-only protocols, so they do not need or use a VLAN. VLANs are between interfaces, but link protocols do not cross a switch to another interface.